# Owl Carousel and WordPress: Trying to integrate Advanced Custom Fields as Thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel

I'm pretty close, but I need some help. I'm trying to integrate an Owl Carousel using the Owl Carousel Thumbnails Plugin (https://github.com/gijsroge/OwlCarousel2-Thumbs/) but the thumbs don't show up in my code example underneath the slides.

My question is what to do with the data-thumb area inside of the div that contains the slide image, which does appear. Inside of data-thumb is the URL to the thumbnail. Is that what's supposed to appear there? Or should I add img src?

This is my code:

```
<section class="scroll-section cmi-carousel" data-index="<?php echo $i; ?>">
  <div class="grid--parent">
    <div class="grid-12 grid-cell" data-aos="fade">
      <?php if( have_rows('slides') ): ?>
        <div class="cmi-carousel-wrapper">
          <div class="owl-carousel">
            <?php while( have_rows('slides') ): the_row(); 
                $slides_image = get_sub_field('slides_image')['url'];
                $slides_thumbnail = get_sub_field('slides_thumbnail')['url'];
                $slides_heading = get_sub_field('slides_heading');
                $slides_copy = get_sub_field('slides_copy');
            ?>
            <div data-thumb='<?php echo $slides_thumbnail; ?>'><div class="slide-img"><img src="<?php echo $slides_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slides_heading; ?>" /></div></div>
              <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think another example in plugin docs will help (need two loops)

```
<div class="owl-carousel" data-slider-id="1">
    <div>Your Content</div>
    <div>Your Content</div>
    <div>Your Content</div>
    <div>Your Content</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-thumbs" data-slider-id="1">
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">slide 1</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">slide 2</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">slide 3</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">slide 4</button>
</div>
```

Block with thumb separately.
The plugin demo implements in the same way.
http://gijsroge.github.io/owl-carousel2-thumbs/